# Tracking Discord with GA4

Tags: node.js, npm, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

### Bots are amazing, unless you're Google Analytics

After many months of learning to host my own Discord bot, I finally figured it out!  I now have a node server running on my localhost that sends and receives data from my Discord server; it works great.  I can do all kinds of the things I want to with my Discord bot.

Given that I work with analytics everyday, one project I want to figure out is how to send data to Google Analytics (specifically GA4) from this node server.

**NOTE**: I have had success in sending data to my Universal Analytics property.  However, as awesome as that was to finally see pageviews coming into, it was equally heartbreaking to recall that **Google will be getting rid of Universal Analytics in July of this year**.

I have tried the following options:

1. **GET/POST requests to the `collect` endpoint**

This option presented itself as impossible from the get-go.  In order to send a request to the collection endpoint, a `client_id` must be sent along with the request itself.  And this `client_id` is something that **must** be generated using Google's client id algorithm.  So, I can't just make one up.

If you consider this option possible, please let me know why.

2. **Install googleapis npm package**

At first, I thought I could just install the `googleapis` package and be ready to go, but that idea fell on its face immediately too.  With this package, I can't send data to GA, I can only read with it.

3. **Find and install a GTM npm package**

There are GTM npm packages out there, but I quickly found out that they all require there to be a window object, which is something my node server would not have because it isn't a browser.

### How I did this for Universal Analytics

*My biggest goal is to do this without using Python, Java, C++ or any other low level languages.  Because, that route would require me to learn new languages.  Surely it's possible with NodeJS alone... no?*

I eventually stumbled upon the idea of actually hosting a webpage as some sort of pseudo-proxy that would send data from the page to GA when accessed by something like a page scraper.  It was simple.  I created an HTML file that has Google Tag Manager installed on it, and all I had to do was use the [`puppeteer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) npm package.

It isn't perfect, but it works and I can use Google Tag Manager to handle and manipulate input, which is wonderful.

Unfortunately, this same method will not work for GA4 because GA4 automatically excludes all identified bot traffic automatically, and there is no way to turn that setting off.  It is a very useful feature for GA4, giving it quite a bit more integrity than UA, and I'm not trying to get around that fact, but it is now the Bane of my entire goal.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9888366?hl=en

[image: GA4 says "no"]

### Where to go from here?

I'm nearly at the end of my wits on figuring this one out.  So, either an npm package exists out there that I haven't found yet, or this is a futile project.

Does anyone have any experience in sending data from NodeJS to GA4? (or even GTM?)  How did you do it?

Comment: " In order to send a request to the collection endpoint, a client_id must be sent along with the request itself. And this client_id is something that must be generated using Google's client id algorithm. So, I can't just make one up." This the one you want; you have to get a client_id from Google. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/authorization

Comment: I get Service Unavailable when I go there.  Is it an endpoint?  If so, what do I send to it?

Comment: That URL refers to reporting, I need to collect data.

Comment: The client_id used to access the API is needed to interact with the API, in either direction. I linked a doc that explains Google's authentication for GA.

Comment: See also: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events

Comment: I get "Service Unavailable" for both links you posted.

Comment: If you can't get to these URLs, you have a bigger problem.

Answer (score 1):

> ...and this client_id is something that must be generated using Google's client id algorithm. So, I can't just make one up...

Why, of course you can. GA4 generates it pretty much the same as UA does. You don't need anything from google to do it.

Besides, instead of mimicking just requests to the collect endpoint, you may just wanna go the MP route right away: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4 The links @**dockeryZ** gave, work perfectly fine. Maybe try opening them in incognito, or in a different browser? Maybe you have a plugin blocking analytics urls.

Moreover, you don't really need to reinvent the bicycle. Node already has a few packages to send events to GA4, here's one looking good: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ga4-mp?activeTab=readme

Or you can just use gtag directly to send events. I see a lot of people doing it even on the front-end: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ga-gtag Gtag has a whole api not described in there. Here's more on gtag: https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference Note how the library allows you to set the client id there.

The only caveat there is that you'll have to track client ids and session ids manually. Shouldn't be too bad though. Oh, and you will have to redefine the concept of a pageview, I guess. Well, the obvious one is whenever people post in the chan that is different from the previous post in a session. Still, this will have to be defined in the code.

Don't worry about google's bot traffic detection. It's really primitive. Just make sure your useragent doesn't scream "bot" in it. Make something better up.